# Does connection string of application insight change by any action in Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

Does app insight connection string change by itself or by any action which cause changing in it?

```
InstrumentationKey=xxxxxxxxxxxxx;IngestionEndpoint=https://westus-8.in.applicationinsights.azure.com/;LiveEndpoint=https://westus.livediagnostics.monitor.azure.com/
```

Here we observing in IngestionEndpoint that westus-8 is changing to westus-7 or westus-9 by some action in code or somewhere or byitself (maybe)

Can you please let me know whether could it be possible?

just a query? whether could it be possible ? if yes, then what are the actions causing change in app insight's connection string

Comment: [From Application Insights team] IngestionEndpoint should not change. If it does then it warrants a support ticket. Feel also free to start a thread with my SO alias at MSFT. Will need either resource id or instrumentation key to look it up.

Answer (score 0):

> Does app insight connection string change by itself or by any action which cause changing in it?
> IngestionEndpoint that westus-8 is changing to westus-7 or westus-9 by some action in code or somewhere or byitself

No, we can't change the **IngestionEndpoint** in Application Insights. Once configured our Application with Application Insights We cannot change the Connection String information of Application Insights.

To change the connection string information, use the below work around.

##### Before changing connection string

[image]

Changing Connection String of Application Insights using Az Cli

```bash
$Resource_Group_Name = "<Resource Group>"
$App_Insights_Name = "<App Insights Name>"
$Fun_App_Name = "<Function name>"

$Key_Conn = az resource show -g $Resource_Group_Name -n $App_Insights_Name --resource-type "microsoft.insights/components" --query properties.ConnectionString
#Delete the app settings in function app
az functionapp config appsettings delete --name $Fun_App_Name --resource-group $Resource_Group_Name --setting-names "APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING"
#set the application insight for function app
az functionapp config appsettings set --name $Fun_App_Name --resource-group $Resource_Group_Name --settings "APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING = $key_Conn"
```

[image]
[image]

[image]

##### After Added Connection String in APP Settings

[image]